# How to read the first element/term of a line in Java?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

My aim is to read the first element/term of each line from a given input file and then decide what to do (using an `if-else` construct) depending on what that first element is. I.e. if the first element/word happens to be `"the"` (as mentioned in the code below), then I have to skip that line and move to the next line.

I have written the following code till now but I am not sure on how to read only the first element of each line of the text file that I am passing as input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String line;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

                String term  = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
                if (term.equals("the")) {
                    //Code on what to do depending on the first character of each line. 
                }
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println(sb.toString());    

            }

        } 

        System.out.println("Done!");

    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    finally {

        try {

           if (br != null)
               br.close();

        }

        catch(IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Yes. It did work. Thank you.

Comment: @shashank2493, `Yes. It did work` then don't forget to "accept" the answer that inspired your solution by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simple code that prints `the` as the output. you can use this and no need to create an extra array or use StringTokenizer.

```
String s = "The a an the abcdef.";
System.out.println(s.contains(" ") ? s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")) : s);
```

Comment: (1+) good solution so you don't automatically tokenize the entire line each time. (although it would have the same problem I mentions if there is ever only a single word on a line).

Comment: @camickr - I have missed that point. Check the updated condition. It will definitely resolve that.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was just going to suggest. It got my up vote because I don't see the need to tokenize the entire line just to check first word on the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn each term into an array of words via:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    String word = line.split("\\s+")[0];
    if(word.equals("the")){
                //Code on what to do depending on the first character of each line. 
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println(sb.toString());    

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringTokenizer` is considered as legacy class. It is only there for backward compatibility. Use `split()` on string to  split the single string into array of strings/words.

```
String[] s = line.readLine().split(" ");
String firstWord = s[0]; // ->First word
```

So your code can be edited to

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try
        {
            String line;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {

                System.out.println(line);

                String s = line.split(" "); // instead of StringTokenizer


                    if(s[0].equals("the"))
                    {
                        //Code on what to do depending on the first character of each line. 
                    }
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());    


            } 

            System.out.println("Done!");

        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        finally
        {

            try
            {

                if (br != null)
                br.close();

            }

            catch(IOException ex)
            {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }
```

**Note:**

Don't use `startsWith(...)` to check for the first word because it checks by character-wise instead of word-wise. If you want to check for the word `the` then the words `there`,`their` also returns `true` which might break your code.

Try to use `split()` instead of `StringTokenizer` from now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

> but I am not sure on how to read only the first element of each line of the text file that I am passing as input.

There are a couple of different solutions depending on your exact requirement.

1. You can read the entire line of data and then use the `String.startsWith(...)` method to test for the first word. Using this approach you don't tokenize all the data if you just want to skip the rest of the line. Then if you want to continue processing you can use the `String.substring(...)` method to get the rest of the data from the line.
2. You can use the `Scanner` class. The `Scanner` allows you to tokenize the input as you read the data from the file. So you can read the first word and then determine whether to skip the rest of the data or read the rest of the line.

Comment: But `String.startsWith(...)` doesn't work if the first words are `there`,`their` etc.. I think you missed that.

Comment: @SkrewEverything - you include the ending space in the test string. ie `startsWidth("the ")`

Comment: I think I missed that.

Comment: @SkrewEverything, although I guess there could only be a single token on each line in which case that wouldn't work either :) As I said the solution depends on the exact requirement.